# Numerical strategies for evaluating a modular invariant infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-forms, na.numerical-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I'm working on a problem that involves the numerical evaluation of the following infinite sum:

$$
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \ln \left|1\pm e^{-2\pi \tau_1 \sqrt{m^2+x^2/(4\pi^2\tau_1)}-2 \pi i \tau_0 m} \right|^2
$$

where $\tau_1 >0$ and $\tau_0, x \in \mathbb{R}$, more specifically $\tau = \tau_0+i\,\tau_1$ is the modular parameter, i.e. the hole expression, of which not everything is shown here, is invariant under modular transforms.

I've been trying different numerical summation methods, such as the Levin transformation and Richardson extrapolation, but the problem seems to be quite tricky and success very hit or miss. Mapping $\tau$ always back to the fundamental domain seems to help convergence, but is not reliable.

What strategies might be effective in dealing with this kind of problem? Are there any specific extrapolation or summation methods that you would recommend, or any mathematical transformations that could simplify the summand function?

Edit: Just to clarify, modular invariance in this case means, that the total expression is invariant under the operations:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
 \mathcal{S}: \quad &\tau\to-\frac{1}{\tau} \quad\quad &&\text{(Inversion)} \\
\mathcal{T}: \quad &\tau\to \tau+1 \quad\quad &&\text{(Translation)}
\end{alignat}
$$
Where $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T$ are the generators of the modular group. This helps to narrow down the parameter space and could aid convergence. I played around with these transforms but only with limited success.

The [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) is one region of the upper half plane, where no point within can be transformed through the action of the modular group to another point within that region, i.e. one of the (infinite) regions containing all relevant values of $\tau$.

[image: The gray area shows part of the fundamental domain.]
The gray area shows part of the fundamental domain.